# JQuery UI AutoComplete Code Issue with Function as Source

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So essentially, I have tried to move to a function that does the work for the `source` parameter in the autocomplete method, and now the script is broken. No options show up upon typing even though values are being returned by the `$.get(...)` request.

The HTML:

```
           <tr class="itemTableRow">
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="item" name="items[]" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="range" class="quantity" min="1" max="10000" name="quantity[]" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="versionSelect"><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

The Javascript:

```
 $(function() {

            $( ".item" ).autocomplete({
                            source: function(request, response){var data = $.get("http://mydomain.com/dev/kohana/utils/items/search?searchType=maxList&amp;term=" + request.term + "&amp;version=" + $(".item").parent().parent().children(":nth-child(3)").children("select").val()); console.log("" + data); response(data);},
                            minLength: 2
                        });
});
```

The resulting HTTP GET Request URL (when CP is entered in input field):

```
http://mydomain.com/dev/kohana/utils/items/search?searchType=maxList&term=CP&version=5
```

The resulting HTTP Response Body:

```
[{"label":"CP1031L","value":"CP1031L"},{"label":"CP1031M", "value":"CP1031M"]
```

I also have included the Jquery UI default stylesheet on the page, although it was working before that. I feel like I am missing something very basic with how the functional callback is supposed to work. Can anybody spot the problem? Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the `response(data)` on the success handler of your `.get()` call, like this:

```
$( ".item" ).autocomplete({
                            source: function(request, response){var data = $.get("http://mydomain.com/dev/kohana/utils/items/search?searchType=maxList&amp;term=" + request.term + "&amp;version=" + $(".item").parent().parent().children(":nth-child(3)").children("select").val(), function(data) {response(data);});},
                            minLength: 2
                        });
```

Comment: Yep, I was just about to answer my own question. Sometimes it the simple things. Thank you for looking it over though. Note however that I did need to `.parseJSON` data however for some reason.